# What can we use for exist query in magento2?

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

We have two approaches to find if the record exists in database or not

> First

```
$select = $this->bookResource->getConnection()->select()
->distinct()
->from(
    $this->bookResource->getMainTable(),
    "author_id"
)
->where("author_id = ?", $authorId);
if ($this->bookResource->getConnection()->fetchOne($select)) {
      //record exist
}
```

> second

```
$bookCollection->addFieldToSelect('author_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter("author_id", $authorId);
if ($bookCollection->getSize()){
    // record exist
}
```

which one to use and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the first one but with a limit.

```
$select = $this->bookResource->getConnection()->select()
->distinct()
->from(
    $this->bookResource->getMainTable(),
    "author_id"
)
->where("author_id = ?", $authorId)
->limit(1);
```

This will run a query like `SELECT DISTINCT(..) FROM ... WHERE author_id = ... LIMIT 1`.

Without the limit, if there are multiple rows matching your criteria, all will be retrieved from the db and one will be returned.
The second approach, with `getSize` runs a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) from ... where...`. it may run slow if you have a lot of records.

But if you want to respect the [Law Of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) you can use a combination of the 2.

```
$bookCollection->addFieldToSelect('author_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter("author_id", $authorId)
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->setCurPage(1);
$book = $bookCollection->getFisrtItem();
if ($book->getId()) {
    //a row exists
} else {
    //there is no row for the selected author.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class testIfExist
{
/**
 * @var ResourceConnection
 */
private $resourceConnection;

/**
 * @param ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
 */
public function __construct (
    ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}

/**
 * @param string $pageId
 * @return bool
 */
public function execute(string $id): bool
{
    $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();

    $tableName = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('table-name-here');

    $qry = $connection->select()
        ->from($tableName)
        ->where('entity_id_of_table = ?', $id);

    return (bool)$connection->fetchOne($qry);
}
}
```

easy class to call

Cheers

Comment: check the wrong closed parenthesis